# Why isn't 'lightblue' a valid CSS color?

Tags: html, css

When I write

```
background-color:lightblue;
```

In IntelliJ, it highlights `lightblue` and suggests I replace it with `#add8e6`.

I rather like lightblue, it's much more readable. Was it "banned" from the specs? Should I do as IntelliJ suggests?

Comment: But the question is, how light of a blue should "lightblue" be? :P

Comment: They also banned the color 'poopbrown'. Can you imagine?

Comment: it should be camel case according to firebug :) try `lightBlue` or `LightBlue`

Comment: @Steven You used to be able to use color="crap" in IE which evaluated to the greeny-brown colour with hex #c0a000

Comment: @Teneff: the W3C recommendations don't use `StudlyCaps`, just lowercase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nearly(*) authorative list of colors supported in CSS3 is listed in the W3C proposed recommendation [CSS Color Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/), section 4.1 [Basic color keywords](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#html4). `lightblue` is only listed under the [Extended color keywords](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color) of section 4.3.

The non-normative profiles of section 7 suggest that HTML only supports the basic colors, while the extended ones are permitted in SVG.

(*) *Nearly* because this is a proposed recommendation. It does describe current practice.

Comment: So in practice I should use the exact color spec (how is it called btw?) instead of the name? It's a shame, really, the css is much more human readable this way.

Comment: @ripper: for HTML usage, limit yourself to the list of 17 basic colors and RGB values, or your colors may not be portable across browsers/platforms. (I agree it's too bad they only standardize this small number of colors, but it's just the way it is.)

Comment: @larsmans - will do, thanks. IntelliJ even made the auto-complete automatically change the color to the RGB value, so they must really want me to use RGB here...

Comment: @larsmans - I'm not clear from section 7, whether they are referring to color names used in the CSS when applied to HTML, or whether they are referring to the color names used directly in HTML e.g. the color attribute on the `<font>` element. If the former, it seems wrong - The HTML language should not impose limitations on the CSS language, and as far as I know never does. The application of the combination of the two is purely a browser implementation matter.

Comment: @Alohci: "Each specification using CSS3 Color must define the subset of CSS3 Color features it allows and excludes." So apparently, HTML *may* impose limitations on CSS.

Comment: @larsmans - right, but then it says the HTML4 excludes the opacity property, which it clearly doesn't in the use of CSS with HTML, but HTML *natively* doesn't support the property. Which implies that it's documenting HTML's native color use, not its use when CSS is applied to a DOM that is formed from the parsing of HTML.

Comment: @larsmans - Oh OK, I missed your point. It depends on what we mean by limitation. I think that the HTML4 profile is a back-formation of how HTML color names would have been defined, if they had been defined in terms of CSS3 colors. I guess that's a limitation of sorts, so OK.

Answer (score -2):

There are just 17 standart colors: aqua, black, blue, fuchsia, gray, grey, green, lime, maroon, navy, olive, purple, red, silver, teal, white, and yellow. If you use that, IntelliJ don't change it to the hex code. The remianing 130 colors are substituted to ther hex value.

Herer is a list of all color names: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp

Comment: @Joachim Sauer Can someone explain to me why everybody hates w3schools around here ?

Comment: @dwarfy: The same link as in the previous comment has the answer: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: w3schools.com is to HTML/CSS what [roseindia.com](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/06/what-is-it-with-roseindia.html) is to Java.